# Group List of Dics by one key of Dict

Tags: python, django, data-structures, data-manipulation

So, I'm working with Django (Python) and I want to manipulate a data structure in the serializer.

I have this:

```
"week_task_schedule": [
  {
      "id": 3,
      "week_number": 2,
      "task": 1
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "week_number": 1,
      "task": 2
  },
  {
      "id": 1,
      "week_number": 1,
      "task": 1
  }
]
```

I want to get this:

```
"weeks": [
    {
        "week_number": 1,
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "task": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "task": 1
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "week_number": 2,
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "task": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What should be my approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

With a for loop you can iterate over the structure and build a new version like:

#### Code:

```
def transform_data(data):
    new_data = {}
    for record in data:
        new_data.setdefault(record['week_number'], []).append(
            {k: v for k, v in record.items() if k != 'week_number'})
    return [{'week_number': k, 'tasks': v} for k, v in new_data.items()]
```

This uses [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to auto populate the `week_number`  You can also use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).  after the `for` loop, a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is used to take the resulting dicts and create the desired list.

#### Test Code:

```
data = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "week_number": 2,
        "task": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "week_number": 1,
        "task": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "week_number": 1,
        "task": 1
    }
]


new_data = transform_data(data)
print(new_data)
```

#### Results:

```
[{'week_number': 2, 'tasks': [{'id': 3, 'task': 1}]}, 
 {'week_number': 1, 'tasks': [{'id': 2, 'task': 2}, {'id': 1, 'task': 1}]}
]
```